# Can't post gist with pry

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, pry

At minute 4 of `pry`'s introductory screencast http://pry.github.com/ Josh Cheek says to run `gist -m #String.each_line` (actually he says something else but that is this year's version of the command). When I do so I get:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'
```

What have I done wrong or what else do I need to do?

I'm using

```
[40] pry(main)> pry-version
Pry version: 0.9.9.6 on Ruby 1.8.7.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not directly a pry problem but a problem in the `gist` gem, see here, for more information: https://github.com/defunkt/gist/issues/98